# linked list in C programming

Tags: c, linked-list, structure, dynamic-allocation

I don't know what is wrong with this code. when I "display" items that I entered from the "ADD", there are many unnecessary items being displayed. Why is this happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct list
{
    char name[20];
    int age;
    char gender[10];
    struct list *next;
};

void main(void)
{
    struct list *HEAD = NULL;
    struct list *temp, *trav;

    char choice;


    while(1)
    {
        clrscr();
        printf("MENU\n");
        printf("A) ADD\n");
        printf("B) DISPLAY\n");
        printf("X) EXIT\n");

        scanf("%c", &choice);
        switch(toupper(choice))
        {
            case 'A':
                temp= (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
                printf("Fill-Up the following:\n");
                printf("Name:");
                fflush(stdin);
                gets(temp->name);
                printf("Age:");
                fflush(stdin);
                scanf("%d",&temp->age);
                printf("Gender:");
                fflush(stdin);
                gets(temp->gender);


                if(HEAD == NULL)
                {
                    HEAD = temp;

                }
                else if(HEAD!=NULL)
                {
                    for(trav=HEAD; trav->next != NULL; trav= trav->next);
                    trav->next=temp;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Not Enough Memory!\n");
                }


                break;
            case 'B':

                if(HEAD==NULL)
                {
                    printf("Linked List is Empty!\n");
                    getch();
                    break;
                }
                if(HEAD!=NULL){
                    for(trav=HEAD; trav != NULL; trav=trav->next )
                    {

                        printf("Name: %s\n", trav->name);
                        printf("Age: %d\n", trav->age);
                        printf("Gender: %s\n", trav->gender);
                        getch();
                    }
                }

                break;
            case 'X':
                free(HEAD);
                free(trav);
                free(temp);
                exit(1);

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you malloc temp you set all the elements except next.  The next element MUST be set to NULL.

Comment: Your decision to ignore indeterminate values for your pointers isn't wise. Ex: Start this up and enter X, and you immediately invoke *undefined behavior* upon freeing both `trav` and `temp`, neither ever being given valid content. And a side note, that this also uses `gets()`, a function so vile it has been *removed* from the standard library, doesn't help matters. Failure to check even a single function result, the non-standard `fflush(stdin)`, the list could get pretty large before its done with.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah ah! thanks! it works, :D no more garbage when i "display"

Comment: @WhozCraig okay, i will change my code. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You are initializing temp like this:

```
 temp= (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
```

But you never initialize the values of your structure.  So they contain garbage.  All malloc() does is return a chunk of memory to you from the Heap.  You are responsible for its care and feeding, so set all the data members to known values, such as NULL, etc.
This is very evident if you use a debugger, and examine the value of temp after the mallloc() assignment (see image). [image: memory dump]

So, the take-away is to always initialize the data members of your malloc'd structure.

Comment: He does initialize the name, age and geder with keyboard input.  It's the next member that is important.